# literature/reference request for estimates of first eigenvalue of certain Schrodinger operator on compact surfaces

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, riemann-surfaces, geometric-analysis

On compact Riemannian surfaces (say without boundary), the Schrodinger operator I am interested in is of the form $-\Delta+2\kappa$, where $\kappa$ is the Gauss curvature. For minimal surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$, this is the Jacobi operator coming from the second variation of area. I am wondering if there are any recommended references/surveys on estimates on the first eigenvalue and other spectral properties of this operator.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, not all is known about this Schrödinger type operator. The best I know is the [following paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.02755.pdf) and reference therein.